# Если значение ячейки по сути список. Как правильно с ним работать?

Tags: python-3.x, строки, pandas, list, dataframe

Отрывок кода с примером [primer.txt](https://yadi.sk/d/m4md5O9fgmoBtg):

```py
import pandas as pd
df_raw = pd.read_csv('primer.txt', sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-8',low_memory=False)
def naimen_zak_spis(row):
    line = row['namen_zak']
    line = line.replace('[', '')
    line = line.replace(']', '')  
    line = line.split("', '")
    line_result = []
    for i in range(2, len(line), 3):
        line_result.append(str(line[i]))
    return line_result
df_raw['namen_zak_spis'] = df_raw.apply(naimen_zak_spis, axis=1)
df = df_raw.filter(items = ['nomer_zak', 'namen_zak', 'namen_zak_spis', ])
print(df.iloc[0]['namen_zak'])
print('')
print(df.iloc[0]['namen_zak_spis'])
df.head()
```

Результат кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ячейке `df_raw['namen_zak']` содержится список, он выглядит как список, но при попытке работать с ним как со списком, ничего не получилось, он воспринимается как строка.

Есть ли возможность работать с ним как со списоком?

То есть в функции обработки `naimen_zak_spis` выбирать данные с помощью индексов,
например `result = line[5]`, создавать циклы перебора по этому списку.

Сейчас же мне приходится этот список-строку разделять с помощью `split`
и делать снова списком.

Скажите, что я не учёл? Можно ли, например, задать при импорте тип этого столбика - "список" или есть ли ещё какое либо более четкое решение этой ситуации?

Comment: Добавте свой пример на хостинг кода или прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Извините я не понял ваш комментарий

Comment: Primer.txt возможно явно в вопросе показать без ссылок?

Comment: он длинный, не уверен что это визуально удобно, точнее уверен что это весьма неудобно для понимания вопроса, проще в текстовом редакторе посмотреть

Comment: @ДенисАстаховский, да, существует нормальное решение для парсинга подобныз строк. __НО__ в вашем случае строка в столбце `namen_zak` не парсится ни `ast.literal_eval()` ни `json.loads()` ни `yaml.safe_load()`! В вашем примере некорректный JSON, поэтому его невозможно распарсить стандартными методами...

Comment: Это наверное из-за лишних кавычек да?

Comment: Я нашёл возможность поправить данные в этом столбике убрав, лишние кавычки и другие нехорошие символы. Теперь данные в ячейке выглядят как натуральный список. Вопрос остался тем же как, работать с ним как со списком?